# How to access default controller config in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes, controller, default

I would like to know whether it is possible to retrieve the default controller set in config/route.php from a controller or a library?

I have tried `$this->load->config('route')` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the default controller by;

```
$this->router->default_controller
```

Answer (score -1):

try the following line. hope it will works for you.

```
$this->router->fetch_class();
```

Comment: This will retrieve the current class, not the default one set in config.